# How to chek database integrity in TYPO3 8.7

Tags: php, mysql, database, typo3, typo3-8.x

On a live system we get "suddenly" such errors as well in Frontend as in Backend:

By calling the **extension manager**:

> PHP Warning: class_parents(): object or string expected in
>   ../typo3_src/typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Persistence/Generic/Mapper/DataMapper.php
>   line 282

By calling **backend user** module
There is no @var annotation for property "userName" in class "TYPO3\CMS\Beuser\Domain\Model\Demand"

By calling **protocol module**
There is no @var annotation for property "userOrGroup" in class "TYPO3\CMS\Belog\Domain\Model\Constraint"

By calling **reports modul** an in several frontend plugins
Could not determine type of argument "action" of the render-method in ViewHelper "TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\ViewHelpers\Link\ActionViewHelper". Either the methods docComment is invalid or some PHP optimizer strips off comments

and so on.

Other modules like the page, list, etc. working fine.

For me, it seems, that there was some problem in accessing the database, but the install tool shows no errors or other hints. Database Compare looks fine.

Any hints on how I can check the integrity of the database furthermore.

Comment: Im not quite sure but In such cases usually, PHP version issue can be issue. Check out the PHP version is properly set

Comment: Thanks fot the hint, it was an PHP configuration issue. PHP Doc comment reflection was broken.